Line breaks in '[ ]' not aligned in Google Colab
I press the Enter key in '[ ]' of a tensor in Google Colab to wrap the line, but the next line does not align with the previous line.
# After pressing Enter, the cursor on the second line is not aligned with the first line  
torch.tensor([[1 ,2],
                         ])

code in Google Colab
I have these settings under tools>settings>editor but it still don't work.
my settings under tools>settings>editor

So I assume this works in both Chrome and Firefox?

Maybe, wrong monospaced font caused this problem.

It's a problem with the monospaced font in Microsoft Edge, just try changing to another monospaced font.
